# Database field retrieval using Php on Cloud9

Tags: php, html, cloud9-ide

have been having some trouble displaying information from my database in the online IDE cloud 9. I have followed some guides about connecting to databases and retrieving information, but it doesn't seem to enter the while loop that actually echo's the information to the browser.

**PHP**

```
$host = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$username = "tannerhallman1";
$password = "";
$database = "Charlotte";
$dbport = 3306;

// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully my dude(".$db->host_info.")";
?>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lenders";
    $records = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "$records"

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Local Lenders</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width = "600" border = "1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing = "1">
<tr>

<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Company</th>
<tr>

<?php

while ($lender = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$lender['ID']."</td";
echo "<td>".$lender['First']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$lender['Last']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$lender['Company']."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
} //end while

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server console**

```
==> /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/log/error.log <==
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146489 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client  10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect      to MySQL server on '10.240.52.53' (111) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 13
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146571 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client 10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 16
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146580 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client 10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 19
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146680 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client 10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 24
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146693 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client 10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 24
[Mon Mar 23 13:59:17.146708 2015] [:error] [pid 26008] [client 10.240.52.53:54254] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be     resource, boolean given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lenders.php on line 48
```

**C9 Terminal output**

```
mysql> select * FROM lenders;
+----+--------+---------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | First  | Last    | Company      | Phone     | Bio                                                   |
+----+--------+---------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Tanner | Hallman | UNCW         | 123456789 | I am a cool guy that would be good for your finances. |
|  2 | Wes    | Hallman | Mortgage Pro | 987654321 | I'm a good, cool person.                              |
+----+--------+---------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Output from Browser**
I get the start of a table, with the headers but it doesn't retrieve the data.
I have confirmed that c9 can actually connect to the database using the c9 terminal, so I am lost.

Connected successfully my dude()

ID | First Name | Last Name | Company

Comment: I even followed the directions on this [cloud9 post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460519/cloud-9-ide-cant-connect-to-database) where I manually retrieved the IP and C9_USER from the terminal and manually entered them, still to no avail.

Comment: I think your hostname (`$host`) might be the problem. Try replacing `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")` with `getenv('IP')` and try again.

Comment: I just tried this edit, and but that didn't work. When I retrieve the IP from the c9 terminal, its 0.0.0.0.

Comment: That's correct, `0.0.0.0` should be where you'll find your MySQL running. I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: How are you starting your MySQL?

Comment: I have tried it. `tannerhallman1@mortgageproject:~/workspace (master) $ mysql-ctl start` command yields:  `MySQL already running`

Should I just convert the whole project to a local IDE and ditch the cloud?

Comment: Can you send a message to support@c9.io with your username and workspace name so we can take a close look at what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

`$records = mysql_query($sql);` should be replaced with `$records = $db->query($sql);` or even `$records = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` since you aren't specifying which db should be used to run your query

Then `while ($lender = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {` should be replaced with 
`while ($lender = $records->fetch_assoc()) {` or `while ($lender = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just figured it out last night. I need to stay consistant with `my_sqli` commands and also added the `$db` variable to the statement `$records = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` and it all worked successfully! Thank you for your help.